# Is [NSString hash] computed every time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If I have an immutable string is the hashing algorithm run every time I call hash, or does it remember the value (given that the string can't change)?

Comment: Well to answer with another question, why do you care? If you're worried about performance, then you're clearly worrying too soon since you haven't got any code to profile and discover this for yourself. Furthermore, if Apple doesn't document this behaviour, it could quite happily change in the future, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Perhaps I was interested?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is recomputed.

-[NSString hash] is in fact a call to -[NSCFString hash] (due to toll free bridging).

If you create a program that calls -[NSString hash] on the same string and you break in between the calls and alter the memory backing up the string, you get a re-computed hash value. This tells me there's no caching involved.

```
(gdb) b -[NSCFString hash]
Breakpoint 1 at 0x3b02fa3
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, 0x93652fa3 in -[NSCFString hash] ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
2009-05-13 14:23:39.003 a.out[1754:813] Hash: -327163326
```

Note the hash value.

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x93652fa3 in -[NSCFString hash] ()
(gdb) bt          
#0  0x93652fa3 in -[NSCFString hash] ()
#1  0x00001f73 in main () at test.m:10
(gdb) fra 1
#1  0x00001f73 in main () at test.m:10
10      NSLog(@"Hash: %d", [m hash]);
(gdb) info locals
pool = (NSAutoreleasePool *) 0x109760
m = (NSString *) 0x2030
(gdb) x/20x 0x2030
0x2030 <dyld__mach_header+32>:  0xa06f54a0  0x000007c8  0x00001fa2  0x00000012
```

0xa06f54a0 is the "isa" pointer, 0x00001fa2 is a pointer to the "XXXXXX" string.

```
(gdb) set {int}0x1fa2 = 0x59595959
```

alter the "XXXXXX" string to "YYYYXXXX", then continue to the second hash call

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
2009-05-13 14:24:35.884 a.out[1754:813] Hash: -246144954
```

Note the hash value that is different on the as far as ObjC knows immutable string.

The program I've (de)bugged is:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    NSString * m = [NSString stringWithString:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];

    NSLog(@"Hash: %d", [m hash]);
    NSLog(@"Hash: %d", [m hash]);

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can look at the source code for CFStringRef here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.17/CFString.c

Search for 'CFHashCode __CFStringHash(CFTypeRef cf)' for the function that gets called. Note that it (a) does things differently for 8-bit and Unicode string buffers, and (b) only hashes up to a certain number of characters (currently 96). Search for '/* String hashing:' to see the details of the hashing algorithm(s).

Comment: Good tip Jim, I wasn't aware the source was available online.